# Create a measure that returns multiple columns Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
measure_test =
SWITCH (
    TRUE ();
    SELECTEDVALUE ( menu[option] ) = "1"; SUM ( table[INSCRITOS] );
    SELECTEDVALUE ( menu[option] ) = "2"; SUM ( table[INSCRICOESCOMPLETAS] );
    SELECTEDVALUE ( menu[option] ) = "3"; SUM ( table[PAGARAMINSCRICAO] );
    SELECTEDVALUE ( menu[option] ) = "4"; SUM ( table[AVALIADOS] );
    SELECTEDVALUE ( menu[option] ) = "5"; SUM ( table[CONVOCADOS] );
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        table;
        "a"; SUM ( table[CONVOCADOS] );
        "b"; SUM ( table[AVALIADOS] )
    )
)
```

But, if no option is selected, I want to show all results.

What would a measure look like that would show all other measures?
When selection one:

[image: one]

When nothing is selected, need to show everyone:

[image: all]

Comment: Create 5 measures whose value is chosen by simple "if."    --   that is, Measure A =>  selectedvalue is 1 OR 6 then sum(INSCRITOS) else blank().   Measure B => selectedvalue is 2 OR 6 then sum(INSCRICOESCOMPLETAS) else blank().  etc.   Value 6 on your slicer is a nice 'no filters' or 'select all' option.  Measures whose value is Blank() won't show on your visual.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way to achieve the exact result you are looking for. However, you can get to a close enough result using Bookmarks. You would have to create two tables, one displaying "measure_test" (display one measure at a time) and another table displaying all the measures. Then create the following Bookmarks:

```
Bookmark1 --> Hide Table2 and Display Table1
Bookmark2 --> Hide Table1 and Display Table2
```

You can place the tables in such a way that, it looks like the same table. Now you can create two buttons, one for single selection and other for All measures and assign the bookmarks accordingly.

```
Button1 --> your selections will become active and you can select any single measure. 
Button2 --> your selections won't be active and it will display all measures.
```

This method will not allow you to do multiple selections. I understand this may not be the perfect solution, but it might just do the trick for your specific scenario. Hope this helps.